# Como agrupar y filtrar datos de una lista de objetos?

Tags: java, lista, lambda, stream

necesito una ayuda, tengo una lista de objetos y necesito poder agruparlos y de ese grupo solo retornar el que tenga el menor precio, el objeto inicial tiene esta estructura:

```
public class Producto {
  private String name;
  private String code;
  private Precio precio;
  
  // geters...
}

public class Precio {
  private Double neto;
  private Double tax;
  private Double total;
  
  // geters...
}
```

La lista que tengo tiene varios productos repetidos por la propiedad Producto::code, los estoy agrupando con la siguiente sentencia:

```
Map<String, List<Producto>> results = productos.stream()
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Producto::getCode, Collectors.toList()));
```

Con esta expresión logro tener un mapa donde agrupo por el código los productos y obtengo una lista List pero no he logrado tomar esa lista y filtrar para que solo me retorne el producto que tiene el menor precio total algo como:

```
List<Producto> resultReduc = results.entrySet().stream()
                        .filter(e -> e.getValue().stream().min(Comparator.comparingDouble(Precio::getTotal)))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Yo sé que esto último no funciona, pero es algo por este estilo, al final lo que necesito es tener la lista de productos donde solo estén los productos con menor precio sin tener códigos repetidos, les agradezco si me dan una ayuda al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando agrupas tambien puedes filtra los de menor precio. Modifique tu agrupacion de la siguiente forma para conseguirlo:

```
Map<String, Optional<Producto>> groupedProducts = products.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(
        Producto::getCode,
        Collectors.minBy(Comparator.comparingDouble((p) -> p.getPrecio().getTotal())))
);
```

Luego para obtener la lista de los productos mas baratos el filtro quedarias asi:

```
List<Producto> cheaperProducts = groupedProducts.entrySet().stream()
    .map(e -> e.getValue())
    .filter(Optional::isPresent)
    .map(p -> p.get())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Espero te sirva.

Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, si de esta forma funciona correctamente, gracias

Answer (score 0):

tienes el 90% del trabajo hecho. Pero necesitas Map. A ese Map le pasas data vía List u observableList.

```
private List<claseModelo> listQueQuieresFiltrar;
 //Filtrado y agrupado
    Map<Integer, List<claseModelo>> actualizaConceptoTDTCTRMap = listQueQuieresFiltrar
            .stream()                
            .filter(e -> e.getEstatusVenta().equals( "Activa")) //incluyo solo las ventas activas
            .filter(e->e.getEstatus()== (null) || e.getEstatus()=="Cancelada" || e.getEstatus()== "")//Ingresa solo las que están en estring vacío, null o canceladas.             
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(claseModelo::getIdventa));
```

Si te das cuenta, en el Map filtro según sea el caso

Comment: Si te entiendo, pero lo que no he logrado es en ese filtro determinar cual es el objeto con el mayor precio y que solo retorne ese objeto, ya sea que lo retorne o elimine los otros objetos con precios mayores, también se me ocurrió utilizar un reduce, pero no lo logre implementar, una solución es utilizar lógica imperativa o clásica con un par de ciclos, pero esto me dañaría el performance del proceso y no es la idea.

Comment: Que tal, pero en tu pregunta mencionas que necesitas agrupar, y para agrupar no hay nada mejor que el Map. Aunque observando bien tus clases modelo, ¿Que no neto,tax y total deberían de pertenercer a la clase producto? El map lo recorres con (k,v)->. Donde k es la clave que elijas para agrupar y v el elemento. Dentro del map, podrás hacer ciclos que no afectarían al rendimiento.